# Big Problem when using Class Interface with Custom Event in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wpf

I need to do this (with a custom slider or a standard control ):

```
        ISlider ISlider;
        ISlider = slider as ISlider;
        if (ISlider != null)
        {
            ISlider.CustomEvent += new CustomEventDelegate(MyCustomEventHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            // standard control
            this.slider.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(this.slider_ValueChange);
        }
```

But C# refused because it says interface cannot contain fields (CustomEvent) and if I don't declare CustomEvent in interface my code above cannot compile either so what can I do ?

In the interface ISlider I just tried to declare:

```
CustomEventDelegate CustomEvent ;
```

Comment: Show the code for the ISlider interface declaration.

Comment: Ummm... no, you didn't show the ISlider interface declaration.  Please include the `public interface ISlider { ... }` code.

Comment: Yes I did for the part that is involved event CustomEventDelegate CustomEvent;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CustomEvent should indeed not be declared as a field in ISlider.  It should be declared as an *event*:

```
public delegate void CustomEventDelegate(/*whatever*/);

public interface ISlider {
    event CustomEventDelegate CustomEvent;
}
```

And fix your code so typenames and reference variable names are distinct:

```
    ISlider itf;
    itf = slider as ISlider;
    if (itf != null)
    {
        itf.CustomEvent += new CustomEventDelegate(MyCustomEventHandler);
    }
```

Comment: I did this see my update I have now another problem in the class where I implements ISlider :)

Comment: Because my problem is not solved did you read my post update ?

Comment: Wait, you downvoted *my* answer because *your* question sucked?  Do you kick your dog to get him to do something?  I'm *not* your dog.

Comment: Hey calm down It wasn't nasty from me I didn't know you take points such at heart :) OK I give it you back but my question is still not solved.

Comment: It was a good answer to the original question, no reason to edit it.  I recommend you start a new one.

Comment: OK I will ask another question and mark this one as good answer.

Comment: Subsequent question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776608/how-to-implement-a-custom-event-declared-in-a-class-interface-in-c