# Why I cannot compile a Custom Event declared in a Class Interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, winforms

Let's say I have this:

```
public interface ISlider {
    event CustomEventDelegate CustomEvent;
```

In the class where I implements ISlider, I tried this

```
public CustomEventDelegate  CustomEvent = delegate { };
```

But it says that CustomEvent is not implemented.

I need to do is something like this:

```
   ISlider ISlider;
    ISlider = slider as ISlider;
    if (ISlider != null)
    {
        ISlider.CustomEvent += new CustomEventDelegate(MyCustomEventHandler);
    }
    else
    {
        // standard control
        this.slider.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(this.slider_ValueChange);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply - that is a *field*, not an *event*.

An event is actually a pair of **methods** (like how a property works) - but *field like events* make that trivial (you can even include your default non-null value, which is (I assume) your intent:

```
public event CustomEventDelegate CustomEvent = delegate { };
       ^^^^^ <==== note the addition of "event" here
```

That translates *almost* like:

```
private CustomEventDelegate customEvent = delegate { };
public event CustomEventDelegate CustomEvent {
    add { customEvent += value;}
    remove { customEvent -= value;}
}
```

I say "almost" because field-like events also include some thread-safety code, which is rarely needed but tricky to explain (and varies depending on which version of the compiler you are using).

Of course, in my opinion it is better to not use this *at all*, and just check the event for null:

```
var snapshot = EventOrFieldName;
if(snapshot != null) snapshot(args);
```

---

Example of implementing this interface:

```
public interface ISlider
{
    event CustomEventDelegate CustomEvent;
}
public class MyType : ISlider
{
    public event CustomEventDelegate CustomEvent = delegate { };
}
```

Comment: Ah ok but I'm not sure of what I should do precisely as for my class Interface and my class implementation knowing I need to enforce this event handler upon my class see my post update thanks.

Comment: @user310291 - I don't understand the comment; what you have to do is add the keyword `event`, as per my first example.

Comment: Well I don't understand as I already have the keyword event in my interface class ISlider. And if I paste your code in my ISlider it cannot compile.

Comment: @user310291 - see edit for example; I am talking about the `class`, not the `interface`

Comment: @user: Your interface says "I expose an event".  Your class says "I expose a public field that is a delegate type".  Those are not the same thing.

Comment: Just a comment: if you let Visual Studio help you code, you will notice that it can automatically write the correct syntax to implement an interface :)

Comment: Save your thanks for Marc, I just reiterated what he was already saying ;)  @djechelon: Yes, but that doesn't help one  to understand how this stuff actually works.