# Issue with compilation when testing C# Class Interface support

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I have a WPF UserControl which implements `ISlider` with some CustomEvent (see previous episode [Why I cannot compile a Custom Event declared in a Class Interface in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776608/why-i-cannot-compile-a-custom-event-declared-in-a-class-interface-in-c) ).

Now my problem is the code below doesn't want to compile :

```
        ISlider ISlider;
        ISlider = slider as ISlider;
        if (ISlider != null)
        {
            ISlider.CustomEvent += new CustomEvent(OnCustomEvent);
        }
        else
        {
            this.slider.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(this.slider_ValueChanged);
        }
```

because UserControls don't have a ValueChanged Event like WPF standard controls do.

So the line:

```
this.slider.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(this.slider_ValueChanged);
```

doesn't compile.

So am I obliged to artificially create a `ValueChanged` event in my `ISlider` interface when I have no use of it, just to satisfy the compiler ?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to name the variable exactly like the type. Don't know if that is your issue, but try to rename the variable `ISlider` to `iSlider` anyway.

Comment: You haven't told us which line doesn't compile, and I agree with Albin - you *really* shouldn't name a variable the same as its type... it's bound to cause confusion.

Comment: @Albin: user## was told so before. Doesn't help.

Comment: @John OK I said it implicitely when I said "I don't have a ValueChanged Event which is for the case I use a WPF standard control" it is of course the line this.slider.ValueChanged; otherwise you cannot understand the question.

Comment: My question is not pertaining to naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So am I obliged to artificially create a ValueChanged event ... just to satisfy the compiler ?

Yes.